# Split Opencart Sitemap into multiple columns

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I am using opencart 2.0.1.1 and in the information/sitemap, the categories in the site map is listed in one column and since i have lots of categories it is generating long list in just one column.

I was trying to figure out if i can split the categories in multiple columns to make it look good. I tried using array_chunk or inserting an if condition to split into different columns it doesn't work. 
This is the current code.

```
$data['categories'] = array();

        $categories_1 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

        foreach ($categories_1 as $category_1) {
            $level_2_data = array();

            $categories_2 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category_1['category_id']);

            foreach ($categories_2 as $category_2) {
                $level_3_data = array();

                $categories_3 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category_2['category_id']);

                foreach ($categories_3 as $category_3) {
                    $level_3_data[] = array(
                        'name' => $category_3['name'],
                        'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_1['category_id'] . '_' . $category_2['category_id'] . '_' . $category_3['category_id'])
                    );
                }

                $level_2_data[] = array(
                    'name'     => $category_2['name'],
                    'children' => $level_3_data,
                    'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_1['category_id'] . '_' . $category_2['category_id'])
                );
            }

            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'name'     => $category_1['name'],
                'children' => $level_2_data,
                'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_1['category_id'])
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using css multi column property:

```
column-count
column-gap
column-rule-style
column-rule-width
column-rule-color
column-rule
column-span
column-width
```

Although not a even grid, it does the job in dividing one column into multiple columns. Not an Ideal Solution but is doing the job.